# Trigger event or method in custom user control from Month Calendar control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, monthcalendar

The scenario is the following:
[image]

So i have a Month Calendar control (`monthCalendar1`) and an custom user control (`taskControlPanel1`). This second user control should be able to access to the chosen date at `monthCalendar1` and show the `Task` elements established for that date.

The `taskControlPanel1` control has a `DateTime` variable called `chosenDate`. Using his property (`ChosenDate`), the fact to give a value to `chosenDate` is simple as using the following event:

```
private void DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dateSelected = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start;

        taskControlPanel1.ChosenDate= dateSelected;

        taskControlPanel1.Update();
    }
```

**The problem is that i can't *refresh* or *update* the list once the `chosenDate` variable is set.**

**So, how should i focus on this issue? It is possible to create a `taskControlPanel1` event handling this case?**

What i have tried is to code public methods in `taskControlPanel1` that refresh his `ListView` control, showing the `Task` objects for the new `chosenDate`, but i can`t call them from the Windows Form project that implements this control